# Запуск PHP5 Ubuntu

Tags: apache, php

Помогите пожалуйста, срочно! Я установил php5, вместе с apache2 и т.д. после установки все работало, перезагрузил комп. все перестало работать, ну всмысле apache2 вроде работает, но php нифига, как вызвать пакет php5 на работу

Comment: PHP, случаем, не отдельным демоном (через CGI, например), запускался?

Comment: так апач "вроде работает" или не работает?.. что выводит http://localhost в браузере?

Comment: Пробовали в консоли ввести  

    sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 start
?  
А то "апач вроде работает" как-то смущает, раз у Вас не получилось достоверно определить, работает ли апач.

Comment: да, PHP через Терминал запускается

Comment: Apache пишет что работает, в терминале, логами

Comment: `sudo a2enmod php5; sudo service apache2 reload`
только второе  может не сработать, у меня пакет `service` установлен

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для начала:

1) Проверить, что в httpd.conf (или что его заменяет в конкретной убунте - могут быть отличия) включён сам модуль:

```
LoadModule php5_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so
```

2) Проверить, что апач настроен на правильную обработку файлов php. Например, так:

```
<FilesMatch ".+\.php$">
 SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

Конкретные строчки и конф. файлы могут отличаться, например, загрузка модуля у меня на убунте 12.10 происходит в файле /etc/apache2/mods_available/php5.load

Comment: Чегось? Проверить валидность штатной установки - это кувалдой? Ну-ну :)

Comment: А не очевидно, что '_' вместо '-' это просто опечатка?

Answer (score 1):

Подробностей явно недостаточно. Но можно грохнуть апач с пхп и поставить заново:

```
sudo apt-get purge apache2 php5
sudo apt-get install apache2 php5 php5-cgi libapache2-mod-php5
```

Как-то так.